# Prevent a view from resizing when soft keyboard is open

Tags: java, android

How can I prevent specific views from resizing caused by soft keyboard opening.

I'm aware of the solutions like:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

But those solutions affect the entire activity. I want to keep default resizing on everything except for 3 small views - which are being resized for no particular reason - they are far away from the keyboard.

[Here is how the views are supposed to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sWf6.png)

[Here is one example of resize after keyboard opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv924.png)

[Here is another example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2fsz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the keyboard works on Android

If the mode is adjustNothing, the keyboard pops up and overlaps your app.  This should almost never be used.

If the mode is adjustPan, the app will scroll up so that the cursor is onscreen.  This is a common mode.

If the mode is adjustResize, the app will be resized to fit inside the space above the keyboard.

There is no hybrid mode.  You can't say "adjustResize except these views".  You can write your layout such that individual views have no reason to resize (they have a fixed size, or are constrained into place), but that requires a careful layout and we'd need your entire xml to help you do that.